# Xcode storyboard doesn't show scene

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

After finishing work on one of my screens in my swift project yesterday. I came back to modify it today and saw this:
[image: screenshot]

The screen is still working properly at runtime, I have no idea what could cause this. (Xcode 6.1, iOS 8.2)

Comment: So it still works as it should when running on iPhone / simulator? If that's the case then it's a display but in Xcode, not your fault. I would suggest to restart Xcode if you didn't do that yet.

Comment: Reloaded the project, restarted Xcode, didn't help.

Comment: In the product menu? Didn't work.

Comment: Yes. You can copy ViewControllers, activate the ViewController like shown in your picture. Then press `command` + `c` to, click into the storyboard and then `command` + `v` to paste it again.

Comment: Actually, after I did that, I deleted the rogue segue you see in the pic and my views magically appeared. So thanks. :D

Comment: You can add the segues again, so everything works? I posted that as an answer so other users find it more quickly. Oh and I'd be happy about some credit ;)

Comment: It's not the copying that solved it, it was me deleting the segue by hand. Now I have two scenes with the exact same content. :)

Comment: Oh, maybe you should have used `command` + `x` so one gets deleted. Try that.

Comment: Nah, I'm fine with two, nice to have a backup.

Comment: can you please show me the warnings?
maybe you have something wrong with the ```ibdesingable```.

Comment: It's been 4 years, so I'm afraid not. :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the ViewController by activating the ViewController you want to be copied like shown in your picture. Then press `command` + `x` to, click into the storyboard and then `command` + `v` to paste it again.

**NOTE**

Your segues will be gone, so remember their identifiers and from where, to where they go before copying / pasting the ViewControllers.